# Count values for strings that appear consecutively

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, for-loop

I have a string of text named seq that has values like this: `AATTDYAATTDUUAATTDAATTDAATTDAAAGATAGATAYAMMMCCMMMMMMMMM`

Now I also have a list of values that stores these strings: `['AATTD','AGAT','MMM']`.
What I am trying to achieve with my code is to count how many times every word (not each letter) in the list appears in the text **consecutively** and store the count values of the string in a dictionary.

When I say consecutively, that means in this part of text above,  `AATTDYAATTDUUAATTDAATTDAATTD`, the count for the value `AATD` should be only 3, because the other 2 are separated by `Y` and `UU` separately.

Here's what I have done with my code so far:

```
count = 0
list1 = ['AATTD','AGAT','MMM']
length = len(list1) # The length of the list 
print(length)

seq = open(filepath, "r") # open the file that has the string of text
seq = seq.read()

for i in range(len(seq)):
    for j in list1:
        while (seq[i:len(j)]  == len(j) ):
            if seq[i:len(j)]  == j:
                count += 1
    print (j, count)
```

But this appears to print each string with all 0 as counts. Can anyone help me with this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the desired result correctly, this could be achieved as follows:

**Code:**

```
list1 = ['AATTD','AGAT','MMM']

seq = "AATTDYAATTDUUAATTDAATTDAATTDAAAGATAGATAYAMMMCCMMMMMMMMM"

d = dict()

for s in list1:
    c = 1
    while s*c in seq:
        c += 1
    print(s, c-1)
    d[s] = c-1
```

**Output:**

```
AATTD 3
AGAT 2
MMM 3
>>> d
{'AATTD': 3, 'AGAT': 2, 'MMM': 3}
```

Note also that when reading from the file, you should use:

```
with open(filepath, "r") as f:
    seq = f.read()
```

to avoid problems where you forget to close the file after reading.

Answer (score 3):

> **Note that** this code is not efficient, if your text contains symbols like these:
>
> ### $ ^ * ? \ ( ) { } [ ] +

```py
import re

seq = "AATTDYAATTDUUAATTDAATTDAATTDAAAGATAGATAYAMMMCCMMMMMMMMM"
list1 = ['AATTD','AGAT','MMM']

for word in list1:
    list2 = re.findall("(?:%s)+" % word, seq)
    longest = len(max(list2, key=len))
    print(int(longest/len(word)))
```

> ### Output:
>
> 3
>   2
>   3

Answer (score 2):

One way using `re.findall`:

```
{t: len(re.findall("(({})+)".format(t), seq)[-1][0])/len(t) for t in list1}
```

Output:

```
{'AATTD': 3.0, 'AGAT': 2.0, 'MMM': 3.0}
```

Answer (score 2):

use the regex default package re in python.

```
import re

list1 = ['AATTD','AGAT','MMM']

seq = open(filepath, "r") # open the file that has the string of text
seq = seq.read()

for word in list1:

     # WITHOUT CASE SENSITIVE
     print(word,len(re.findall(word,seq)))

     # WITH CASE SENSITIVE SEARCH
     print(word,len(re.findall(word,seq,re.IGNORECASE)))
```

Re docs : https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html